# Rails 3 and jQuery- how to transmit ruby variable to javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to ask you - I have javascript code and I need into this part of code transmit variable with data from database. This variable is in controller. How can I do it?

I tried something like (in *.js):

```
$("#div").append('<%= escape_javascript(@test) %>hhhhhh');
```

or

```
$("#div").append('<%= @test %>hhhhhh');
```

But the codes above not works... Could you help me, please, how to do?

Thank you, Manny

Answer (score 1):

If you are rendering a response to AJAX-call, that code should go in `your_action.js.erb` file. Otherwise, if it's just inline JavaScript, place it in `your_action.html.erb` under `app/views/your_controller` directory.

Correct me if I understood you wrong.